# why am I getting wrong values with countif statement?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

When I use count the number of days each employee working in a given week I am getting the wrong values. I am expecting 4 for I90 and 4 for I91. I don't know why the results are off.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(C:C; "select C,count(C) where C is not null group by C label count(C)''")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dragging down the formula, is the countif range `C88:C101` in all cases? You may need to fix it with `C$88:C$101` or use an `arrayformula` from cell `I88` like this (deleting all values below):

```
=arrayformula(if(H88:H<>"",countif(C$88:C$101,H88:H),))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, The $ seems to fix the problem